# Error NullPointerException

Tags: playframework-2.0

i created Register Form, that accept uploading image/avatar . But i got this error : `[NullPointerException: null]`

when i accept the form. Here are my codes :

----Register.java----

```
public class Register extends Controller{

static Form<Users> form = form(Users.class);

  public static Result blank() {
    return ok(register.render(form));
  }

  public static Result submit() throws IOException {
    Form<Users> filledForm = form.bindFromRequest();

      MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
      FilePart picture = body.getFile("picture");
      if (picture != null) {
        String fileName = picture.getFilename();
        String contentType = picture.getContentType(); 
 File file = picture.getFile(); // ERROR MARKED IN THIS LINE : NullPointerException

        String orig = file.getAbsolutePath();
        String dest = "/home/thangnk/demo/public/upload/"+fileName;
      }
//Copy file into "demo/public/upload/"   folder     
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(orig);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
           out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
      }
// Check accept conditions
      if(!"true".equals(filledForm.field("accept").value())) {
          filledForm.reject("accept", "You must accept the terms and conditions");
      }

// Check repeated password
      if(!filledForm.field("password").valueOr("").isEmpty()) {
          if(!filledForm.field("password").valueOr("").equals(filledForm.field("repeatPassword").value())) {
              filledForm.reject("repeatPassword", "Password don't match");
          }
      }

// Check if the username is valid
      if(!filledForm.hasErrors()){
          String name = filledForm.field("username").value();
          Finder<String, Users> find = new Finder<String, Users>(String.class, Users.class);
          List<Users> users = find.where().like("username", '%'+ name +'%').findList();

          if(!(users!=null && users.isEmpty())){
              filledForm.reject("username", "This username is already taken");
          }

      }

 if(filledForm.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(register.render(filledForm));
          }
      else{
            Users.create(filledForm.get());
            return ok(register_result.render());
          }
      }
```

----Users.java----

```
@Entity
public class Users extends Model{

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @NotNull
    public String username;

    @Constraints.Required
    @NotNull
    @Constraints.Email
    public String email;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Constraints.MinLength(6)
    @NotNull
    public String password;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String path;

    public Users(){}

    public Users(String username,String email,String password){
        this.username=username;
        this.email=email;
        this.password=password;
    }

      public static Finder<Long,Users> find = new Finder<Long,Users>(Long.class, Users.class); 


    public static List<Users> all() {
        return new ArrayList<Users>();
      }

    public static void create (Users user){
        user.save();
    }
}
```

Register.scala.html

```
 @helper.form(action = routes.Register.submit()) {
              <h3> Create Account Informations </h3>

       @inputText(
                signupForm("username"), 
                '_label -> "", 
                '_help -> "Please choose a valid username.",
                '_error -> signupForm.globalError,
                'placeholder ->"Username"
            )

       @inputText(
                signupForm("email"), 
                '_label -> "",
                '_help -> "Enter a valid email address.",
                '_error -> signupForm.error("email"),
                'placeholder ->"Email"
            )

       @inputPassword(
                signupForm("password"), 
                '_label -> "",
                '_help -> "A password must be at least 6 characters. ",
                '_error -> signupForm.error("password"),
                'placeholder ->"Password"
            )

       @inputPassword(
                signupForm("repeatPassword"), 
                '_label -> "",
                '_help -> "Please repeat your password again.",
                '_error -> signupForm.error("password"),
                'placeholder ->"Repeat password"
            )

       @inputFile(
                signupForm("picture"), 
                '_label -> "",
                '_help -> "Max size 120x130px",
                '_error -> signupForm.error("picture"),
                'placeholder ->"Upload file"
            )

       <a href="#"><h3>Terms and conditions</h3></a>

       @checkbox(
                signupForm("accept"), 
                '_label -> None, '_text -> "You aggree the Terms and conditions",
                '_showConstraints -> false
            )

        <div class="actions">
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Register">
            <a href="@routes.Register.blank"><input class="button" type="button" value="Reset"></a>
            <a href="@routes.Application.index"><input class="button" type="button" value="Cancel"></a>
        </div>
}
```

Help me sloved it. Thanks alot!!!
P/s : If i remove upload file, it's work fine.

Comment: Can you include the stack trace?

Comment: sry i don't understand :) can u explain for me :)

Comment: You said the error is marked on one of the lines in your listing.  I presume this means you ran it, an exception was thrown, and you got the line number from the console.  Can you show what else was in the stack trace in the console?  Otherwise, how do you know that the error is at the marked line?